# Android Login screen from Json

Tags: java, android, json, authentication

I´m newbie on Android and need help.

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
    {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "user",
    "userId": 4,
    "active": true,
    "ProfileId": 1,
    "Tema": "green",
    "Language": "english",
    "success": true,
    "error": false
}
```

Json 2:

```
{"message":"no user or password","success":false,"erroAplicacao":false}
```

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText usernameWidget;
    EditText passwordWidget;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        usernameWidget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
        passwordWidget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_password);

    }// END ON CREATE

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String message = "message";
        String loginSuccess;
        String Id = "Id";


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1){
                    char current = (char) data; // each time creates a char current

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }   // END doInBackground


        //Method called when the doInBack is complete
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.i("***JSON ITSELF***", result);


                loginSuccess = jsonObject.getString("success");
                Log.i("*****LOGIN SUCCESS*****", loginSuccess);
                message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                Log.i("*****MESSAGE*****", message);
                Id = jsonObject.getString("Id");
                Log.i("*****ID*****", pessoaFisicaId);



            }catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//  END CATCH

            if (loginSuccess.contains("true")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (loginSuccess.contains("false")){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }// END POST EXECUTE
    }// END Download Task

    public void login(View view) {
        String user = usernameWidget.getText().toString();
        String pass = passwordWidget.getText().toString();

        String stringJSON = "*URL*login=" + user + "&senha=" + pass;
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute(stringJSON);
        Log.i("*****JSON URL*****", stringJSON);

    }// END LOGIN
}// END MAIN
```

In this order:

```
                loginSuccess = jsonObject.getString("success");

                message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                Id = jsonObject.getString("Id");
```

I get the message ("no user or password") from json2 (different url) as a Toast.

If I change the order, lets say, to:

```
        loginSuccess = jsonObject.getString("success");

        Id = jsonObject.getString("Id");

        message = jsonObject.getString("message");
```

I don´t get a message. In fact I get the value "message" from the String message at the start of the DownloadTask class.

It seems that the json is only getting two values, the first ones I ask for.

One thing though is that only when the user or password is wrong is that the json has a message (json2):

```
{"message":"no user or password","success":false,"erroAplicacao":false}
```

Since my json cant be transformed into an array json (I tried and got error saying this), what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `jsonObject.getString("your_string")`, this will throw a `JSONException` if your string cannot be found. Therefore, the remaining lines in of code in the method will not be executed. Change your LogCat settings to **verbose** and you should be able to see what's going on.

More info on the `getString()` method here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot at better understanding json. xD

Comment: Again, thx a lot. Due to your answer I decided to modify the json for more useful and simple coding here. xD

Comment: @ArthurAbreu no problem! If this answer helped you, you can choose this as the Correct answer on the page.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that either. Done xD

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON

```
public class User{
  private int Id;
  private String Name;
}
```

Parse

```
User user = GSON.fromJSON(jsonString, User.class);
```